# Date comparison slow for large number of joined rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following query groups `Snippets` by `ChannelId` and returns an `UnreadSnippetCount`.

To determine the `UnreadSnippetCount`, `Channel` is joined onto `ChannelUsers` to fetch the date that the `User` last read the `Channel` and it uses this `LastReadDate` to limit the count to rows where the snippet was created after the user last read the channel.

```sql
    SELECT c.Id, COUNT(s.Id) as [UnreadSnippetCount] 
    FROM Channels c
    INNER JOIN ChannelUsers cu
        ON cu.ChannelId = c.Id
    LEFT JOIN Snippets s
        ON cu.ChannelId = s.ChannelId
        AND s.CreatedByUserId <> @UserId
    WHERE cu.UserId = @UserId
    AND (cu.LastReadDate IS NULL OR s.CreatedDate > cu.LastReadDate)
    AND c.Id IN (select value from STRING_SPLIT(@ChannelIds, ','))

    GROUP BY c.Id
```

The query works well logically but for `Channels` that have a large number of `Snippets` (97691), the query can take 10 minutes or more to return.

The following index is created:

```sql
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Snippets_CreatedDate] ON [dbo].[Snippets]
(
    [CreatedDate] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

## Update:

Query execution plan (original query):

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B19sI105F

## Update 2

Moving the `where` clause into the `join` as suggested:

```sql
    SELECT c.Id, COUNT(s.Id) as [UnreadSnippetCount] 
    FROM Channels c
    INNER JOIN ChannelUsers cu
        ON cu.ChannelId = c.Id
    LEFT JOIN Snippets s
        ON cu.ChannelId = s.ChannelId
        AND s.CreatedByUserId <> @UserId
        AND s.CreatedDate > cu.LastReadDate
    WHERE cu.UserId = @UserId
    AND c.Id IN (select value from STRING_SPLIT(@ChannelIds, ',')
```

Produces this execution plan:

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HkqwFk0ct

Is there a better date comparison method I can use?

## Update 3 - Solution

### Index

```sql
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Snippet_Created] ON [dbo].[Snippets]
  (ChannelId ASC, CreatedDate ASC) INCLUDE (CreatedByUserId);
```

### Stored Proc

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetUnreadSnippetCounts2]
(
    @ChannelIds ChannelIdsType READONLY,
    @UserId nvarchar(36)
)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON

SELECT
    c.Id,
    COUNT(s.Id) as [UnreadSnippetCount] 
FROM Channels c
JOIN @ChannelIds cid
    ON cid.Id = c.Id
INNER JOIN ChannelUsers cu
    ON cu.ChannelId = c.Id
    AND cu.UserId = @UserId
JOIN Snippets s
    ON cu.ChannelId = s.ChannelId
    AND s.CreatedByUserId <> @UserId
    AND (cu.LastReadDate IS NULL OR s.CreatedDate > cu.LastReadDate)
GROUP BY c.Id;
```

This gives the correct results logically and returns quickly.

Resulting execution plan:

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=S1GwRCCcK

Comment: The index you've included isn't going to likely help that much, if at all. Your `JOIN` is on `ChannelId` and where `CreatedByUserId` isn't the value of the parameter, and neither of those are in the index (`INCLUDE`d or in the sort order). Also you `LEFT JOIN` to `Snippets` but it appears that it's required that it has a non-`NULL` value. `s.CreatedDate > cu.LastReadDate` should really be in the `ON` clause, not the `WHERE`.

Comment: I originally had the `s.CreatedDate > cu.LastReadDate` in the ON clause but seemed to perform better in the WHERE. Also its fine to exclude null rows because if there is no match, I can assume (in the code) that all snippets are read, reducing the number of rows that are returned.

Comment: Instead of `IN` consider creating a temp table (with a clustered index) from the `string_split(@channelIds)` output.
Then inner join the temp table. Instead of using an `IN` clause

Comment: Side note, don't use single quotes (`'`) for aliases. Single quotes are for literal strings, not delimit identifying object names. Some methods of using single quotes for Aliases are deprecated and only works when you define them, no where else; `ORDER BY 'Quantity'` would *not* order by your column aliased as `'Quantity'`. Stick to object and alias names that don't need delimit identifying, and if you *must* delimit identify them use the T-SQL identifier, brackets (`[]`), or ANSI-SQL's, double quotes (`"`).

Comment: Can you suggest a suitable index @Larnu? Something like:
```CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Snippet_Created] ON [dbo].[Snippets]
(
 [ChannelId] ASC,
 [CreatedByUserId]
 [CreatedDate] ASC.  ```

By the way there is already a clustered index on SnippetId).

Comment: I'll do that @PrebenHuybrechts.
Was trying to get the query to perform well first. I don't think the `string_split` could hurt performance though, right?

Comment: Looking at the clause, you might be better off with the `INDEX` on `ChannelId` and `CreatedDate` and `INCLUDE` `CreatedByUserId`; as it's using a `<>` it's unlikely a seek is going to be used. If `Id` isn't your `CLUSTERED INDEX` either, then include that in the `INCLUDE` too.

Comment: @DanCook, see [link](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2020/11/how-scalar-user-defined-functions-slow-down-queries/)

Comment: `STRING_SPLIT` is certainly likely to hit performance. Also `AND (cu.LastReadDate IS NULL OR s.CreatedDate > cu.LastReadDate)` doesn't seem right, this will cause an `INNER JOIN` effect in the event `LastReadDate` is not null. You should probably move the second condition to the `ON`

Comment: You might even be better off `JOIN`ing to `STRING_SPLIT`: `JOIN STRING_SPLIT(@ChannelIds, ',') SS ON c.Id = SS.[value]`. Though if you could use a Table Type Parameter, that would likely be better.

Comment: @Larnu I would be surprised if `JOIN` makes much difference compared to `IN`, if anything it could make it worse

Comment: The `INDEX`, a `JOIN` to `STRING_SPLIT` or the `TTP`, @Charlieface ?

Comment: There are only ever max 5 `@ChannelIds` passed in. I will do anyway

Comment: I'm starting to feel like you're repeating me now, @Charlieface , lol (though if we're both saying the same that, that' a good thing).

Comment: @Larnu Argh, missed that in the chain. But really we need to see a full query plan, which OP can share via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts That link is not relevant, as `STRING_SPLIT` is a TVF not a scalar UDF. It's still problematic, but for a different reason: lack of statistics, ordering and uniqueness guarantees

Comment: I'm not sure your statement about the "inner join effect" is true @Charlieface. I often use this pattern. If the user has never read the channel `LastReadDate` will be NULL and therefore all snippets are unread. If its not null, only rhe snippets created after `LastReadDate` are unread.

Comment: It's fine, @Charlieface, like I said, it's good to see we both agree on the `INDEX` choice and that the `s.CreatedDate > cu.LastReadDate` clause should be in the `ON` . :)

Comment: @DanCook if you move that clause to the `ON`, you can completely remove the `cu.LastReadDate IS NULL` clause; as the `JOIN` will fail in the event `cu.LastReadDate IS NULL` is true, but the row isn't omitted as it's a `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Updated answer with link to query execution plan

Comment: @DanCook But what happens if you have a `Channel` for which all `ChannelUsers` have `LastReadDate IS NOT NULL` but there is no matching `Snippets` *at all*: then you will completely lose that row

Comment: Thats ideal @Charlieface, because then in the calling code I can assume all relevant snippets are unread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There are a number of inefficiencies I can see in the query plan.**

1. Using `STRING_SPLIT` means the compiler does not know how many values are being returned, or that they are unique, and the data type is mismatched. Ideally you would pass in a Table valued Parameter, however if you cannot do so then another solution is to dump them into a table variable

   ```
   DECLARE @tmp TABLE (Id int PRIMARY KEY);
   INSERT @tmp (Id)
   select value
   from STRING_SPLIT(@ChannelIds, ',')
   ```
2. You need better indexing on `Snippets`. I would suggest the following

   ```sql
   CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Snippet_Created] ON [dbo].[Snippets]
     (ChannelId ASC, CreatedDate ASC) INCLUDE (CreatedByUserId);
   ```

   It doesn't make sense to place `CreatedByUserId` in the key, because it's an inequality. Keep it in the `INCLUDE`
3. As you have already been told, it's better if you move the conditions (for left-joined tables) to the `ON` clause. I don't know if you then still need the `cu.LastReadDate IS NULL` check, I've left it in.
4. I must say, I'm unclear your schema, but `INNER JOIN ChannelUsers cu` feels wrong here, perhaps it should be a `LEFT JOIN`? I cannot say further without seeing your full setup and required output.

```sql
SELECT
  c.Id,
  COUNT(s.Id) as [UnreadSnippetCount] 
FROM Channels c
JOIN @tmp t
    ON t.Id = c.Id
INNER JOIN ChannelUsers cu
    ON cu.ChannelId = c.Id
    AND cu.UserId = @UserId
LEFT JOIN Snippets s
    ON cu.ChannelId = s.ChannelId
    AND s.CreatedByUserId <> @UserId
    AND (cu.LastReadDate IS NULL OR s.CreatedDate > cu.LastReadDate)
GROUP BY c.Id;
```

Comment: Channels should only be returned if there is a ChannelUser record for @UserId (i.e. user is a member of the channel). However the user might not have read the channel, so `LastReadDate` will be null. If they have never read the channel, ALL `Snippets` are unread. If they have read the channel, all `Snippets` created after the `LastReadDate` are unread. That's why I need the `LastReadDate IS NULL OR`, otherwise `Snippets` wouldn't be included in the `count` if `LastReadDate` is null, right?

Comment: TableVariables are also bad, they will always estimate 1 row. Suggest using a temp table, then you have statistics.

Comment: @DanCook Yes, that sounds right. But you probably don't need an `INNER JOIN` given you aren't taking any data from `ChannelUsers`

Comment: Made the final adjustments. Stored proc is blazing now, thank you all